# Database being not updated

Tags: php, mysqli

```
mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='$name' rollnumber='$nrollnumber' mark='$mark' department='$department' WHERE rollnumber='$rollnumber'");
```

is there any quotes rule violation in the code.because the DB is not being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing comma's,

```
mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='$name',rollnumber='$nrollnumber', mark='$mark', department='$department' WHERE rollnumber='$rollnumber'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE student SET name='".$name."', rollnumber='".$nrollnumber."', mark='".$mark."', department='".$department."', WHERE rollnumber='".$rollnumber."'");
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.